# How to check this condition with enums - C++

Tags: c++, enums

Class Direction

```
class Direction
{
public:
 enum value
 {
  UP,
  RIGHT,
  DOWN,
  LEFT,
  STAY
 };
};
```

Class Point

```
 #include "Direction.h"
        class Point {

         int x , y;

        public:

         Point() { x=0; y=0; };
         Point(int x1 , int y1) : x(x1) , y(y1) {};
         void setX(int newX) { x = newX; };
         void setY(int newY) { y = newY; };
         int getX() { return x; }
         int getY() { return y; }
         void move(Direction d) {
          if(d==UP);
        };
```

The problem is `if(d==UP)` I don't understand how can I check the condition I receive an error checking this.

Any ideas?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`UP` is declared inside `class Direction`, so outside that scope you should write `Direction::UP` to refer to it:

```
if (...something... == Direction::UP)
    ...
```

Your `Direction` class creates the `value` enumeration type, but doesn't have any data members yet, so it's not clear what in `d` you might want to compare to `Direction::UP`.  You could add a data member by inserting an extra line just before the final `};` in `class Direction`:

```
value value_;
```

Then your comparison would become:

```
if (d.value_ == Direction::UP)
    ...
```

All that said, if your `class Direction` is not going to contain anything other than the `enum`, you might consider getting rid of the class part altogether and simply declaring the enum alone:

```
enum Direction { UP, ... };
```

Then your comparison would simplify to:

```
if (d == UP)
    ...
```

Comment: when I write the following command : `if (d == Direction::UP)` I receive error C2676: binary '==' : 'Direction' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator, Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: @JaVaPG: perhaps re-read from "Your `Direction` class... doesn't have any data members".

Answer (score 3):

I think you didn't need to having create class `Direction`. Simple enum is enough.

```
enum class Direction
{
    UP,
    DOWN,
    LEFT,
    RIGHT,
    STAY,
};
```

Then you can write similar function to following one:

```
void do_move(Direction d)
{
    switch (d) {
    case Direction::LEFT:
        cout << "LEFT" << endl;
        break;
    case Direction::RIGHT:
        cout << "RIGHT" << endl;
        break;
    case Direction::UP:
        cout << "UP" << endl;
        break;
    case Direction::DOWN:
        cout << "DOWN" << endl;
        break;
    case Direction::STAY:
        cout << "STAY" << endl;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

And simply call it:

```
Direction d = Direction::UP;
do_move(d);
do_move(Direction::STAY);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you really want is `Direction` to be an enum, not a class:

```
enum Direction { UP, RIGHT, DOWN, LEFT, STAY };
```

Now you can call `move` simply like this:

```
move(UP);
```

And your `if(d==UP);` will work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I notice your `Direction` class doesn't have anything except an enum in it, in that case you could simply:

```
enum class Direction {
  UP,
  ...
};
```

The difference is with `enum class` the enumerations will be encapsulated in it. You will still have to do `if (d == Direction::UP)`.

If you make it a regular enum:

```
enum Direction {
  UP,
  ...
};
```

Then you can directly `if (d == UP)` as in your original code.

Also, this way you can have `Direction d` which is a little more conspicuous than `value d` or `Direction::value d`.

What you have now is a regular enum which is not encapsulated in `value` but is encapsulated in the `Direction` class in which `value` is. You can only address it directly inside `Direction`, but outside of it, you will have to specify the scope of the encapsulating class.

Comment: critical/key observation, and great answer

Answer (score 0):

```
if(d.value == UP)
```

d is of Type `class Direction` not of Type `Enum value`.
Hence you cannot compare `d` and `UP